# GE front load washer model WCVH6800J1WW doesn’t agitate or spin in wash mode

Tags: washing-machine

GE front load washer model WCVH6800J1WW doesn’t agitate or spin in wash mode. At start of wash cycle it fills with water. Then pumps out water no problems. But never spins or agitates. Pauses until press the Start/Pause button which begins the water fill again. This cycle continues again and again as the timer continues to count down. At very end of cycle time I switch over to the Spin/Drain setting which does spin and drain as normal. Therefore clothes only wash as water passes thru. Never agitation or spin on any wash settings.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What are some possible problems / failures? Could it be a fault timer?

Comment: Could be the timer/control board, could be a clutch/brake mechanism, could be a transmission problem. First, take the cover off and look/listen near the motor area. If it doesn't make noise of any kind while trying to spin on its own during the cycle, you could have a timer or control board issue.

Comment: If it makes noise, the brake could be hung up not allowing it to move. I would lean more towards a timer or board issue if you can get it to manually spin. Cheapest and easiest if you want to just start with part throwing, would probably be the timer, followed by board(only because it would mean less teardown), clutch (usually just a gear(plastic/rubber) between the motor and transmission), then the brake (disassemble the drum and or pull the drum and motor/transmission out). Being front load, I would suggest it is most likely the control board.

Comment: Have you tried to "reset" the controls? Some have a button sequence to reset the wash cycles. Try that first! Also checkout the website repairclinic.com and go to the troubleshooting section for the GE front load machines.

Comment: @Allen, putting the question into a comment does not count .... your post still has no question ..... I added it for you